# Materials and procedures for painting acrylic (Plexiglass) sheet

Tags: paint, plastic, surface-preparation, acrylic-glass

I would like to paint acrylic sheet (Plexiglass) with acrylic paint.  Both the sheet and the paint are opaque (black or white); single color all over.

- What kinds of paint should I use? What kinds of paint should I avoid?
  Are all acrylic paints created equal? My local home improvement store
  carries acrylic paint, and they can make a variety of colors on the
  spot; would that paint work?
- How to prepare surface? Do I need to apply primer first?  If so, what
  kind of primer?
- What can I use as varnish on top of the paint?

To put this question into perspective, painting is only the 1st stage of the process.  In the 2nd stage, I will burn off the paint with a laser.  So, if I've got black acrylic with white paint, and I ablate the paint selectively, then I will have black details on white background.  (This is not unlike [LaserMax](http://www.rowmark.com/laser/LaserMAX/lasermax.asp) sheets.)

I know how to do the laser.  I don't know how to do the paint.

Comment: What location are the sheets going to end up? External or internal? Do anticipate a protective layer once the lasering is complete?

Comment: @BeaglesEnd  Indoor location (front panel of an electronic device, for example).  I would like to to add a protective layer after laser engraving, if I can figure out what kind of varnish to use for that.

Comment: The other key question: are you expecting the plexiglass to flex? If it does, then you will get cracks.

Comment: @Rory  The Plexiglass panel will be flat at all time.  It will not flex.  It will not carry mechanical loads.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the underlying panel will not flex, yes, you can use normal acrylic paints, but a primer is required, and the recommended method is to fine sand the plexiglass to a slight roughness, then cover with primer.

Acrylic polymer varnish is ideally suited to varnishing over acrylic paint, and I'm pretty certain you can use other varnishes.

Answer (score 0):

Painting on a plexi surface can be challenging! I'd clean with alcohol to prep.
I'm not a big user of acrylcs but I do know there are quality gradations and I suspect the higher the quality the better the bonding.  Were I in your shoes I'd ask or go buy price.

Understand that static electricity may play one of those challenging roles.  To combat it, keep a moist/damp rag or paper towel in touch with the plexi sheet. Another problem will be the susceptibility to scratching.  To protect your work a sheet of clear plexi would, in my opinion, be better than a clear spray.  Still, if a clear varnish like cover is what you want, clear spray acrylic, should be available where you buy your paint.